# load time relocation and virtual memory

Tags: linker, loader, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I am wondering what load-time relocation actually means on a system with virtual memory support.I was thinking that in a system with virtual memory every executable will have addresses starting from zero and at run-time the addresses will be translated into physical addresses using page tables.Therefore the executable can be loaded anywhere in memory without the need of any relocation. However this article on shared libraries  mentions that linker specifies an address in the executable where the executable is to be loaded (Entry-point address).

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/

Also there are many articles on dynamic linking which talk about absolute addresses.
Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: Load-time relocation and virtual memory are two independent, orthogonal concepts. Load-time relocation usually refers to loading code at variable addresses *inside* a given (virtual) address space.

Comment: Can you point me to some article which explains this in detail ? I am unable to comprehend this "relocation within virtual address space thing".

Comment: Hm, not of the top off my head, but perhaps you can crawl Wikipedia starting [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_code) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

Comment: Thanks for links  but they do not explain what it means by relocation in virtual address space. I need to understand if and how virtual memory and relocation work together.Also, could you please tell the significance of the Entry point address ?

Comment: Relocation is not related to virtual address space (at least not at the level of library loading; we're not talking about the implementation of the OS memory manager here). You have to know some assembler to know how an executable looks like on the inside. Now you notice that there are memory addresses in there. Now consider what happens when those addresses aren't actually fixed, but depend on *where* the library gets loaded inside the address space.

Comment: In the simplest case when there are no  shared libraries, is load time relocation required ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Load-time relocation and virtual memory support are two different concepts. Almost all CPUs and OSes these days have virtual memory support. The only really important point to understand about virtual memory is this: forget physical addresses. That is now a hardware and OS responsibility and, unless you are writing a paging system, you can forget about physical addresses. All addresses that a program uses are virtual addresses. This is a huge advantage and immensely simplifies the programming model. On 32-bit systems, this simply means that each process gets its own 4 GiB memory space, ranging from `0x00000000` to `0xffffffff`.

An `.exe` represents a process. A linker produces `.exe` from `.obj` files. While both are binary files, `.obj` files are not executable because they do not contain the addresses of all the variables and functions. It is the job of the linker to provide these addresses, which it determines by placing these `.obj` files end-to-end and then computing the exact addresses of all the symbols (functions and variables). Thus, the `.exe` that is created has every address of  functions and variables "hard-coded" into it. But there is still one critical information needed before the `.exe` can be created. The linker has to have insider knowledge about where in memory the `.exe` will be loaded. Will it be at address `0x00000000`, or at `0xffff0000`, or somewhere else? For example, in Windows all `.exe`s are always loaded at an absolute starting address of `0x00400000`. This is called the base address. When the linker generates the final addresses of symbols (functions and variables), it computes those from this address onward.

Now, `.exe`s rarely need to be loaded at any other address. But the same is not true for `.dll`s. `.ddl`s are the same as `.exe`s (both are formatted in the portable executable (PE) file format, which describes the memory layout, for example, where text goes, where data goes, and how to find which one). `.dll`s have a preferred address, too. This simply means that the linker uses this value when it computes the addresses for symbols inside the `.dll`. If the `.dll` is loaded at this address, then we are all set.

But if the `.dll` cannot be loaded at this address (say it was `0x10000000`) because some other `.dll` had already been loaded at this address, then the loader will find some other space in memory and load the `.dll` there. However, the global addresses of functions and symbols in the `.dll` are now incorrect. Thus, the loader has to do a *relocation* (also called "fixup"), in which it adjusts the addresses of all global symbols and functions to reflect their actual addresses.

In order to do this adjustment, the loader needs to be able to find all such symbols in the `.dll`. The PE file has a `.reloc` section that contains the internal offset of all such symbols.

Of course, there are other details, for example, regarding how indirection can be used when the compiler generated the code so that, instead of making direct calls, the calls are indirect and variables are accessed via known memory locations in the header of the `.exe`.

Finally, the gist is this: You need relocation (of some sort) to adjust addresses in the call and jump as well as variable access instructions when the code does not load at the position (within the 4 GiB address space) it was expected to load.  When the OS loads a `.exe`, it has to pick a suitable place in this 4 GiB address space where it will copy the code and data chunks from this `.exe` on disk.