# How do JMP and CALL work in assembler?

Tags: assembly, compilation, x86, memory-address

If you compile, link and run something like this:

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
jmp message

proc:
...

message:
    call proc
    msg db " y0u sp34k 1337 ? "

section .data
```

1. How does the machine know where he needs to jump? I guess "message:" and "proc:" are translated to adresses.
2. Do "message:" and "proc:" have absolute or relative addresses?
3. If I compiled the programm on my PC and execute it on another PC, how can it work on the other machine? I mean regarding the addresses for "message:" and "proc:". Will it be always a different address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, they are translated to addresses. There are different `jmp` instructions for relative or absolute jumps or far or near jumps. The assembler will choose one of them (e.g., the shortest one) and translate the mnemonic (`jmp`) to the corresponding machine code.
2. They have relative addresses. The assembler produces an object file, which contains *relocatable code and data*. It can be combined with other object files by a linker to finally yield an executable. The executable in the end has *absolute addresses*<sup>1</sup>.
3. No. Every process has its own virtual address space, so each process's very first address is `0x00`. The addresses used in an executable are virtual too, so they map to arbitrary physical addresses.
   Besides, it's obviously required that the PCs have

   - the same architecture (PC usually means x86)
   - an operating system using the same executable format/object file format

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, that's not true. The image may be [relocated at load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193888/load-time-relocation-and-virtual-memory).