# What is the purpose of relocation when vitrual memory is used?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, relocation

I understand what is relocation and virtual memory. However, I cant think of why modern OSes wouldn't be able to load a program at its preferred address, if the preferred address is virtual memory. Isn't relocation kind of not required with OSes capable of mapping the same virtual memory to different physical addresses?

Comment: Great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193888/load-time-relocation-and-virtual-memory

Answer (score 0):

The first reason is for shared objects.  If shared objects were unable to "run from anywhere", then mapping them into a given process might fail if the desired addresses were already in use.

A secondary reason is to disrupt the predictability of the programs execution; by starting the program from a randomly chosen address each time it is run, malware targetting the program has to work harder to make usable exploits.

A tertiary reason is that it is easy, especially with ARM, and amd64 architectures.  These arch's shy away from  "mov %rax, <64bit-address>", in favour of "lea %rax, symbol(%rip)" or "mov %rax, symbol@GOTPCREL(%rip)".  In the former case, the address is relative to the program counter; in the former, the GOT, which contains the address, is relative to the program counter.  The loader (in the kernel, not the ld command), thus need only rewrite the GOT.

It is more cumbersome in i386 architecture, since it has a weak pc-relative model.